# Cast HashMap to Vector

Tags: optimization, rust, memory-management

Is there a way to cast HashMap to Vector in Rust w/o copying the elements, i.e. move data from hash map to vector? By using iter+map+collect requires to copy all elements of hash map, which is non-optimal as hash map is not assumed to used further. In case of Option it works pretty well, as data it moved automatically and we can use as_ref to prevent it.

Code example where I have to copy all elements

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Clone, Hash, PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
struct base1 {
    x: i32,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct base2 {
    x: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ss {
    x: base1,
    y: base2,
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(base1 { x: 13 }, base2 { x: 13 });

    let vec: Vec<ss> = map
        .iter()
        .map(|x| ss {
            x: x.0.clone(),
            y: x.1.clone(),
        })
        .collect();
    println!("Ma13: {:?}", vec);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to reuse the memory as `HashMap` is laid out in memory differently than `Vec`. However, if you don't need the map anymore, you don't need to clone, and you can instead use `into_iter()`:

```rust
let vec: Vec<ss> = map.into_iter().map(|x| ss { x: x.0, y: x.1 }).collect();
```

There will be no difference with your example since `i32` is zero-cost to clone, but for e.g. `String` it'll make a difference.

You can shorten it even more:

```rust
let vec: Vec<ss> = map.into_iter().map(|(x, y)| ss { x, y }).collect();
```